# Create/Modify folder actions from terminal in OSX

Tags: macos, file-management

I have a set of folders that have similar folder actions attached to them. I want to create a folder action to attach to their parent folder, so that if I create a new folder within it, this folder will have the same folder actions already set up.

In my case I am attaching folder actions to directories in my music folder; I have folder actions  set up to organise the albums within each artist folder, and also actions attached to the album folders. I want to set up the music folder so that if I add a new artist folder to the music directory, that folder will have the same actions all the other artist folders already have, and the same for the album folders.

If at all possible, I'd like to know how to find out what if any actions are already assigned to a folder, and also how to attach new ones; the one caveat being that I want to write this into a script so that it is done transparently.